# How To Remove the desktop.ini file from dataframe when using os Module in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, desktop.ini

I'm super new to python and I'm creating a dataframe of files using the os module. I've seen another question about deleting the desktop.ini file, but I'm still learning how exactly to apply certain things to my code.

With the .ini file present, I can't get a total for my third column. Here's what I have:

import os
import pandas as pd

```
dir_path = r'C:\Users\file\path\whatever'
files = []

for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
    files.append(path)
    
labels = ["Invoice","Vendor","Amount"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict(zip(labels, x.split(" "))) for x in files)
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.rstrip('.pdf')

fund_totals={}

df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True)
print(df)
```

Which will give me a dataframe like this:

```
14              bb             Expense   131.69
15     desktop.ini                 NaN      NaN
16              dh             Expense    60.98
Total          NaN                 NaN      NaN
```

How can I delete the desktop.ini file?

Comment: Before defining `labels`, you could just write `files.remove("desktop.ini")`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is definitely the simple solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't dug deep but this suffices for a solution:

```
import os

dir_path = r'desktop_ini_files'
files = []

for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)) and path != 'desktop.ini':
        files.append(path)
    
print (files)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes it does thank you so much! I knew there was a simple solution